# No logro instalar composer en Windows

Tags: composer

No se que ocurre, pero no logro la creación de los archivos de composer.

Siguiendo el sitio: https://getcomposer.org/download/
Se descarga un archivo .phar, pero siguiendo el resto de las isntrucciones, no ocurre nada.

Este es el directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto lo que ocurre en la linea de comandos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero nada, no se crean las carpetas de composer y quiero utilizar PHPMailer ademas.

Comment: ¿No tienes instalado composer en Windows? Esto choca con lo que dices que ocurre en la línea de comandos. El comando composer install no es para instalar composer en sí, sino para que composer instale en el directorio actual los paquetes indicados en el archivo composer.json, pero como éste no existe, por eso no hay nada que instalar, actualizar o quitar. Y lo raro es que si puedes usar el comando composer, es que ya está instalado. Quizá tu siguiente paso sea requerir un paquete que necesites, esto se hace mediante composer require, y, además de instalar el paquete, creará composer.json

Comment: Si tengo instalado composer, pero no genera las carpetas en el directorio

Comment: Para que te cree las carpetas, tienes que decirle qué paquetes necesitas, esto se hace con composer require. Te pongo respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comando composer install no es para instalar composer en sí, sino para que composer instale en el directorio actual los paquetes indicados en el archivo composer.json, pero como éste no existe, por eso no hay nada que instalar, actualizar o quitar.

Utiliza composer require, esto te creará la carpeta vendor si no la tienes, dentro meterá las carpetas del paquete que quieres instalar, y creará el archivo composer.json si no lo tienes (que según tu pregunta así es).

Uso de composer require:

```
composer require vendor/package:version
```

Ejemplo:

```
composer require refinery29/test-util:0.10.2
```

Para instalar **phpmailer**:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Comment: Correcto, hasta donde busque en el sitio, en ningun momento mencionaban de ese modo el composer require. Si use el ultimo, el del phpmailer, pero no los otros.

Answer (score 0):

Desde el sitio de Composer https://getcomposer.org/download/ descarga el **instalador para Windows** (es un archivo .exe). No lo instales por línea de comandos (archivo .phar).

[image: getcomposer.org/download]

Comment: eso ya lo hice, y no paso nada